# VBA - AND logical operator not working as expected

Tags: vba, logic, bitwise-operators

I was just running some code and got an unexpected error and I realized it's because one of my if statements ran when it wasn't supposed to due to an And operator.

My statement:

```
If 3 And -6 then
```

This evaluates to true and the If executes (but it shouldn't). The 3 and -6 ultimately come from other Or and Not statements.

I went to another sheet to see what was happening

```
x = 3 And -6
```

This returns x = "2", which evaluates to True in an If statement (but I want it to be false).

If I compare `1 And -6` or any other negative number it will be false as expected, but not for numbers greater than 1.

I read somewhere that VBA's logical operators are bitwise (which don't allow short-circuit programming, causing me many headaches), does this have something to do with it and is there any way to get an And that works more classically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: You should be using `=` or `<>` operators. See my "Answer" for explanation of what you observed.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to short circuit `And` is to move the and part in a nested if statement (for example `If a And b Then` becomes `If a Then : If b Then`), but that's not your problem ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just misinterpreted the **`AND`** operator.

When you do an `And` operation on 2 numbers, it do a bit wise **AND**. Put into a simplest byte, it is doing what it should be.

For **3 And -6** (3 in binary is `0000 0011`, -6 is `1000 0110`):

```
0000 0011 (3)
1000 0110 (-6)
0000 0010 (AND result = 2)
```

The same for **1 And -6**:

```
0000 0001 (1)
1001 0110 (-6)
0000 0000 (AND result = 0, same value as False)
```

For the **If** conditions, only zero (0) is considered False, anything else is True, so that's exactly what you observed. You can verify this by `?cint(true)` and `?cint(false)` in Immediate window.

Comment: Okay thanks, I added CBool() to the other operators which now makes the And evaluate Booleans instead of integers.